# Jquery and javascript not working in visual studio 2012

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Why javascript and Jquery effects just disappear after a second when coded in asp.net c# visual studio 2012?

the result is displayed just for a second in the browser and then it disappears.

here is the code

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button1").click(function () {
            $("#div1").empty();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div1" style="background-color: lightpink; height: 200px; width: 300px;">
        <p>
            This is first paragraph
        </p>
        <p>
            This is second paragraph
        </p>
        <p>
            This is third paragraph
        </p>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Remove Content" />
</form>
```

Comment: Use the developer tools in the browser and see what's going on in the console. Maybe there's some errors

Comment: Try to post your code...

Comment: please explain what are you exactly trying to do? what is your goal and what are you getting?

Comment: i m just adding simple jquery effects. but when i click the button the effects just give me a blink for a second and then the content changes to its original state. thats in aspx page.

Comment: i have done it just need to write e.preventDefault in the click function

       $('#<%= mybutton.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
           <head runat="server">
            <title></title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[id*="button1"]').click(function () {
                $('[id*="div1"]').html('');
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="div1" style="background-color: lightpink; height: 200px; width: 300px;">
            <p>
                This is first paragraph
            </p>
            <p>
                This is second paragraph
            </p>
            <p>
                This is third paragraph
            </p>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Remove Content" />
    </form>
```